# How to insert multiple records inside a table created in a hadoop environment

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, cloudera-cdh, impala

I have 22 million records as a comma delimited file with no headers. I also have a separate file which includes all the headers ie the schema of the table. I am using cloudera's distribution of Hadoop and want to specifically use Impala to do basic aggregation on the data. To do that I first created a table using Impala with the header file I had. I now want to insert those 22 million records in this table. I can use the normal SQL insert operation but that will be to tedious a task. Is there a way I can directly insert those records in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have created the table using the header schema. It would be easy if you create the table as an external table with location as the file location.Thereby you could avoid the insertion task. Refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables)